# Re-declaring Variables with Access Modifiers in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

If I declare a variable to be private, am I able to re-declare it in another method?

This is key because I used Netbeans to generate my GUI code, and it uses the same names for variables every time.  Is there any way that I can avoid having to change every variable?

ADDITION/EDIT: Does this also apply for the methods themselves?  How about objects?

Comment: Could you paste your code? A variable couldn't be redeclared while this variable is existing

Comment: Okay, it will be on an edit.  Wait, do you mean the ENTIRE code? Because that would mean over 2000 lines...

Comment: No, I think is fine, I was not sure to understand your problem but with the answers below it is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variables inside a method can not be declared with visibility modifiers (`public`, `private`, `protected` or default), only the attributes of a class can use those modifiers.

You can reuse the same variable names across different methods, it won't cause conflicts. It's a good practice to name the local variables in a method with different names from those of the attributes of the class. To make myself clear:

```
public class Test {

    private String attribute1; // these are the attributes
    private String attribute2;

    public void method1() {
        String localVariable1; // variables local to method1
        String localVariable2;
    }

    public void method2() {
        String localVariable1; // it's ok to reuse local variable names
        String localVariable2; // but you shouldn't name them attribute1
                               // or attribute2, like the attributes
    }

}
```

Comment: So, if two methods have variables with the same name, can their values can be different?

Comment: Yes, I know.  It doesn't let me accept the answer until ten minutes after I ask it.

Answer (score 3):

A local variable and a private instance variable, even with the same name, are two different variables. This is allowed. The local variable hides the instance variable. The only way to access a hidden instance variable is to prefix it with `this.`

Answer (score 2):

This is valid, if this is what you are referring to :

```
public class Experiment {

    private int test;

      public void again()
        {
            int test ;   //the local variable hides the previous one
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following

```
public class Example {

  private String outerString = "outer";

  public void exampleMethod(){
    String outerString = "inner";
    System.out.println(outerString);      // prints "inner"
    System.out.println(this.outerString); // prints "outer"
  }
}
```

The variable outside the method is shadowed by the variable with the same name within the method.  This kind of thing is discouraged because it's easy to get confused. You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming).